# Multiple values added to the same record - MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, itemColors:

```
itemID INT(11)
color1 VARCHAR(7)
color2 VARCHAR(7)
color3 VARCHAR(7)
color4 VARCHAR(7)
color5 VARCHAR(7)
```

I have data instances where I need to add up to 5 values to an item. But the item will not exist until I create it. I say up to because it's just that.

e.g.

```
item1
value1=1
value2=2

item2
value1=10
value2=20
value3=30
value4=40
value5=50
```

The values come from an array so i'm presuming

```
foreach ($array as $value){
    // add $value here
}
```

I'm not sure how to deal with different array lengths input into the same item. Ideas welcome. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if i get it right, you want to insert row with your item, but u dont know how many of columns (with color values) you will need to insert?

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you want correctly, First you can check the array size by using `count(array())` in order to prevent more than 5 values. But for different values, just use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($YOUR_ARRAY); $i++) {
        $value.$i=$YOUR_ARRAY[$i]; // value1=your array value - value2=array value and so on...
    }
```

Then, You are able to do any manipulations with your values.

Comment: Its one row for all values with itemID - not a row each

Comment: You can create your own array in loop.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume your array is

```
    $array_name = array( 'blue' , 'red' , 'green', 'black' , 'white');

    foreach($yourArr as $name => $color) {
      //your insert query here
      $color = mysql_real_escape_string($color);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES ('$array_name')";
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
   }
```

Comment: Its one row for all values with itemID - not a row each

Comment: mysqli_field_count() would be helpful in this case

Comment: more over i think its a dynamic creation of table if i am right